# Как изменить свойство Text у элементов управления другой формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

При переключении радио кнопки должно меняться свойство Text у элементов управления формы f1. Что не так?

Код:

```
public partial class FormSettings : Form
    {

        public FormSettings()
        {


            if (radioButtonRussian.Checked)
            {
                Program.f1.buttonOpen.Text = "Открыть";
                Program.f1.buttonCountUp.Text = "Подсчитать";
                Program.f1.buttonSave.Text = "Сохранить";
                Program.f1.labelInfo.Text = "Введите текст или выберите файл с текстом";
                Program.f1.buttonClear.Text = "Очистить";
                Program.f1.labelWarning.Text = "ВНИМАНИЕ! Приложение работает только с текстом на русском языке!";
                Program.f1.buttonClear.Text = "Выход";
                Program.f1.buttonHelp.Text = "Справка";
                Program.f1.buttonSettings.Text = "Настройки";
                Program.f1.Text = "Подсчет символов";
            }
            else if (radioButtonEnglish.Checked)
            {
                Program.f1.buttonOpen.Text = "Open";
                Program.f1.buttonCountUp.Text = "Count up";
                Program.f1.buttonSave.Text = "Save";
                Program.f1.labelInfo.Text = "Enter text or select a file with text";
                Program.f1.buttonClear.Text = "Clear";
                Program.f1.labelWarning.Text = "ATTENTION! The app only works with text in Russian!";
                Program.f1.buttonClear.Text = "Exit";
                Program.f1.buttonHelp.Text = "Help";
                Program.f1.buttonSettings.Text = "Settings";
                Program.f1.Text = "Count the characters";
            }


        }
   }
```

Скриншот форм:

[image: скрины форм]

Comment: Научись гуглить([ссылка на видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29q1Lz8ErMc))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно обращаться к радио кнопкам не через FormSettings(), а через событие при клике мышью

```
private void radioButtonEnglish_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Это "Form1"**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormSettings f2 = new FormSettings();
        f2.Show();
        f2.Updated += (obj, ev) => ChangeLanguage(f2.language);
    }
    private void ChangeLanguage(string language)
    {
        if(language == "Rus")
        {
            button1.Text = "Russian Button";
        }
        else if (language == "Eng")
        {
            button1.Text = "English Button";
        }

    }
```

> **Это "Form2"**

```
public partial class FormSettings : Form
{
    public FormSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler Updated;

    public string language;
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Updated != null)
        {
            Updated(sender, new EventArgs()); 
            language = "Rus";
        }
    }
    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Updated != null)
        {
            Updated(sender, new EventArgs()); 
            language = "Eng";
        }
    }
}
```